# Filter out items based on metadata using js link

Tags: list-view, view, jslink

I have a document list for a project site.  I have views created for each team.  I also have four categories of documents for each team.  I'd like to be able to have multiple instances of the list on the page, filtered by team and by category.  I could do this with a bunch of views, but that would make setting alerts a little weird.  I can convince them to set an alert based on the team name view, but I don't think setting alerts for four views would fly.  So, what I'd like to be able to do is filter this list in each of the instances using the team name based view, and by category using js link.  Any help on how?

Comment: You might be better of with a Search Webpart and then put your CSR code in a Display Template.... yes.. I know... its confusing all those CSR terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have proper user-groups setup. 
Filter with caml on user Groups in SharePoint designer like so:

```
<Where> 
    <Or>
        <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
            <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
        </Membership>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
        <Value Type="Integer">
          <UserID/>
        </Value>
    </Eq>
    </Or>
</where>
```